# Display Profile Name Instead Of Profile ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a drop down of options that links to the names in a profiles table. They are linked by a key named "profile_id". When I select on of these options and display it in the show page. It shows me the profile_id, but I want to show the name. Can anyone tell me how to do this.

The Form View Selection looks like this:

```
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :profile %><br>
 <%= f.collection_select :profile_id, Profile.all, :id, :name, {:prompt =>  'Please select an Aritst or Band'} %>
</div>
```

The Show View looks like this:

```
<p>
<strong>Artist:</strong>
<%= @album.profile_id %>
</p>
```

The schema is like this:

```
create_table "albums", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "title"
 t.date     "released"
 t.string   "genre"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.integer  "profile_id"
 t.string   "image"
end

create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.date     "born"
 t.string   "bio"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.string   "image"
end
```

The form does give me the correct name options so the tables are linking up correctly. But when I view the results, it gives me the profile id and not the name I selected. Now I am aware that is because I have specified for it to do this. But how do I get it to show the name. Can it be done in the show view code or does it have to be converted in the controller or model somewhere.

I intend on that selected option also being a link back to the profile. If you know this also, that would help me out big time.

As always, all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your show action to

```
<p>
<strong>Artist:</strong>
<%= @album.profile.name %>
</p>
```

Comment: Thats it. Perfect. Thank you. I kept trying profile_id.name and scratching my head. Cheers for the help.